# Why does groovyc run afoul of the security manager?

Tags: groovy, centos7

My platform is CentOS 7 groovy 1.8.9-7, which is probably relevant.

```
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 1.8.9 JVM: 1.7.0_99 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_99"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.5.0.el7_2-x86_64 u99-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have a simple groovy file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
println System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

If I run it, it works fine, e.g.:

```
$ groovy info.groovy 
/usr/share/java/ant.jar:/usr/share/java/ant/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/antlr.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm-analysis.jar:/usr/shar
e/java/objectweb-asm/asm-tree.jar:/usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm-util.jar:/usr/share/java/bsf.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-cli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/groovy.jar:/usr/share/java
/ivy.jar:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:/usr/share/java/jsp.jar:/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/servlet.jar:/usr/share/java/xstream.jar:/usr/share/java/jansi.jar
```

However, groovyc chokes on it:

```
$ groovyc info.groovy                                                                                                                                                         [19/472]
>>> a serious error occurred: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'info.groovy' Prohibited package name: java.lang
>>> stacktrace:
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'info.groovy' Prohibited package name: java.lang
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:850)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:550)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:499)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:482)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:216)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.commandLineCompile(FileSystemCompiler.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.commandLineCompileWithErrorHandling(FileSystemCompiler.java:179)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.main(FileSystemCompiler.java:163)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:797)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.oldFindClass(RootLoader.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:124)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:692)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:560)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:183)
[...]
```

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using groovy from over 3 years ago? Sounds like you may have Java core libs on your classpath...

Comment: And if you're trying to compile it, remove the `#!/usr/bin/env groovy` line

Comment: It's what's supported on RHEL 7. removing the shebang doesn't appear to make a difference...

Comment: if you want to use that ages old groovy version, you might also have consider using a java version out of that era (and who want's to do that?).  over the different versions of jdk7 there where breaking changes regarding what the jvm is willing to run and what the groovyc generated. you might then want to check the jvm options to disable those.  the next group of error will most likely be some verify errors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out the exact problem, but it seems to be unique to my development environment. Installing groovy in a fresh install of CentOS 7 or RHEL 7 it seems to work fine.